# No se reproducen sonidos en Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, sonido

Al lanzar por ejemplo un mensaje en mi sistema, no se escucha el beep caracteristico, este codigo utilizo para lanzar el sonido Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();

Comment: ¿El equipo donde estás probando el código reproduce otro  tipo de sonidos? ¿Verificaste el volumen?

Comment: El equipo funciona con normalidad en lo que respecta al sonido, este problema ya lo tengo hace unos meses, el volumen esta al maximo